# "Hat" environment

Tags: symbols, environments

For my quantum physics class, I need to prove some commutation relations with operators, but it quickly becomes tedious to write `\hat{A}` every time I want to write an operator.

So I was wondering if there existed or if I could create an environment that automatically added hats to the letters in the environment. Or maybe a font that already has hats included.

Basically, I would want to write something like this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{hat}
        [A,B]=AB-BA
    \end{hat}
\]
\end{document}
```

and end up, when I compile, with the same thing as this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\[
    [\hat{A},\hat{B}]=\hat{A}\hat{B}-\hat{B}\hat{A}
\]
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: For me it is not very easy for several reasons. When I have learned about the commutators used in Lie algebra, I wrote them down one by one. +1 for the question.

Comment: it would be tricky to do (easier in luatex) but would not be useful in `align` as (unlike your example here) all real uses of align will have a `&` and you can not start your environment in one cell and end in another

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75140322/latex-hat-environment

Comment: LaTeX won't let you define an *environment* called `hat` because the directive `\hat` already exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It sets up a LaTeX macro (not an environment) called `\Hats` which passes its argument to Lua for further processing with Lua's powerful `string.gsub` function. Specifically, `string.gsub` is tasked to encase every instance of an uppercase character -- Lua's `%u` "magic character" matches any uppercase letter -- in the argument of `\Hats` in a `\hat` directive. If you want lowercase as well as uppercase letters to be "hatted", just change `%u` to `%a`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for "\luaexec" macro
\newcommand\Hats[1]{\luaexec{%
   tex.sprint (( string.gsub ( "#1" , "\%u", "\\hat{\%0}" )) )}}

\begin{document}
\[
\Hats{[A,B]=AB-BA}
\]
\end{document}
```